# Fargate pod dying after 1 hour

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I'm running some long-running computation using in a container run on Fargate. The container uses the R [PAWS](https://paws-r.github.io/) library to interact with other AWS services. I noticed that these pods die (evicted? I can't see the pod and log anymore) after 1 hour.

After reading up, it seems that k8s 1.22 enables the `Bound Service Account Tokens` feature. This feature projects a volume containing a JWT token which can be used by applications to interact with the k8s API server. The token expires after 1 hour. K8s clients automatically updates these and the k8s API server will reject (and kill?) pods that communicate using expired tokens, forcing the pod to restart.

I use EKS's [IAM Role for Service Account](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/iam-roles-for-service-accounts.html) to assign role to the pod. This provides another JWT token (IAM token) which can be used by client libraries to assume roles.

I do not understand why my pod dies. It all seems to point to the fact that my container interacts with the k8s API server. However, to my understanding, my application only communicates with AWS which uses the IAM token, so expiration of the service account token shouldn't be the cause - am I correct? What other parts can cause the pod to die?

Comment: The most common eviction reason is going to be resource exhaustion. Are you writing anything to ephemeral storage?

Comment: No, I'm not writing anything to storage. All the pods die consistently without a terminating state after 60 mins, so I don't think it's an issue with storage